# Regular Expression .Net

Tags: .net, regex, substitution

I have a situation where I want the regular expression to change the letter "O" to a number "0" if it appears in the first 4 characters of a string.

Example: BO1A6987 should be changed to B01A6987

I am using O(?<=^.{0,4}) successfully but I now need to incorporate a new element to the expression and I'm unclear how to do it.

I need to ignore any strings where the first 4 characters are SPOC but the 5-8 characters should have any letter "O" substitute to number "0".

Example: SPOCBO1A6987 should be changed to SPOCB01A6987

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try:

```
^((?:SPOC)?.{0,3})O
```

And replace with `${1}0`. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Me1IZT/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group:

  - `(:` - Open non-capture group:

    - `SPOC` - Match "SPOC" literally.
    - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
  - `.{1,3}` - Capture 0-3 characters other than newline.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `O` - Capture an uppercase "O".

Replacement is done through a backreference to our 1st capture group but you can't simply use `$1` since we need to follow it up by a zero and the engine may think you refer to the 10th capture group. Therefor use curly brackets around the backreference.

You can also refer to [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%28%3f%3aSPOC%29%3f.%7b0%2c3%7d%29O&i=BO1A6987%0d%0aSPOCBO1A6987+&r=%24%7b1%7d0&o=m) `.Net` demo.

---

**EDIT:**

The above handles only a single occurence. I guess that if you want to replace *all* occurences in the 1st-4th position *or* in the 5th-8th position in the case of a leading "SPOC", you could try:

```
(?<=^(?:SPOC)?.{0,3})(?<!^SP(?=OC))O
```

Where:

- `(?<=` - Open positive lookbehind:

  - `^` - Start line anchor.
  - `(?:SPOC)?` - Optionally capture "SPOC".
  - `.{0,3}` - 0-3 Characters other than newline.
  - `)` - Close positive lookbehind.
- `(?<!` - Open negative lookbehind:

  - `^` - Start line anchor.
  - `SP` - match "SP" literally.
  - `(?=` - Open positive lookahead:

    - `OC` - Match "OC" literally.
    - `)` - Close positive lookahead.
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead.
- `O` - Capture an uppercase "O".

Now simply replace with a zero. See the `.Net` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3aSPOC%29%3f.%7b0%2c3%7d%29%28%3f%3c!%5eSP%28%3f%3dOC%29%29O&i=BO1A6987%0d%0aSPOCBO1A6987%0d%0aSPOCBOO145O%0d%0aSPOCOOOOOOOO%0d%0aSPOOOO&r=0&o=m)

Answer (score 1):

Another option using a lookbehind could be to:

Assert the start of the string to the left not followed by *SPOC* and match any char 0-3 times, or assert the start of the string to the left followed by *SPOC* and match any char 0-3 times.

After the assertion match *O*

```
(?<=^(?!SPOC).{0,3}|^SPOC.{0,3})O
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind

  - `^(?!SPOC).{0,3}` Start of string, assert not SPOC directly to the right and match any char 0-3 times
  - `|` OR
  - `^SPOC.{0,3}` Start of string and match any char 0-3 times
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `O` Match literally

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f!SPOC%29.%7b0%2c3%7d%7c%5eSPOC.%7b0%2c3%7d%29O&i=BO1A6987%0d%0aSPOCBO1A6987%0d%0aSPOC%0d%0aSPO%0d%0aSPOOOOOOO%0d%0aSPOCOOOOO&o=m)

If you want to replace all the O's in the first 8 characters, you can change the quantifier to `{0,7}`

```
(?<=^(?!SPOC).{0,7}|^SPOC.{0,3})O
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f!SPOC%29.%7b0%2c7%7d%7c%5eSPOC.%7b0%2c3%7d%29O&i=BO1A6987%0d%0aSPOCBO1A6987%0d%0aSPOC%0d%0aSPO%0d%0aSPOOOOOOO%0d%0aSPOCOOOOO%0d%0aOOOOOOOO&o=m)

Comment: I think I butchered my regex compared to yours... Hehe. Well done.

Comment: @JvdV Your patterns also solve the problem :-) I was playing around with the lookbehind and came to this one.